# find rotation and scale matrix between tow imagens (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, vision

how I can Find the rotation and scale matrix between tow imagens in Swift?

Whit the code:

```
    let registrationSequenceReqHandler = VNSequenceRequestHandler()
    let requestHomography = VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest(targetedCGImage: cgImage0)
    let requestTranslation = VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest(targetedCGImage: cgImage0)

    var x:CGAffineTransform?

    do
    {
        try registrationSequenceReqHandler.perform([requestHomography, requestTranslation], on: cgImage1)

        if let resultH = requestHomography.results?.first as? VNImageHomographicAlignmentObservation
        {
        let y = resultH.warpTransform
            
    
            print("Original")

            print("\(y.columns.0.x)\t\(y.columns.1.x)\t\(y.columns.2.x)")
            print("\(y.columns.0.y)\t\(y.columns.1.y)\t\(y.columns.2.y)")
            print("\(y.columns.0.z)\t\(y.columns.1.z)\t\(y.columns.2.z)")

            let Q = simd_float3x3(simd_float3(1, 0, 0),
                                  simd_float3(0, -1, Float(baseImage.asHighQualityUIImage!.size.height)),
                                  simd_float3(0, 0,1))
            
            let Q_t = Q.transpose
            
            let newHomo = Q_t * y * Q_t
            
            print("Transf")
            
            print("\(newHomo.columns.0.x)\t\(newHomo.columns.1.x)\t\(newHomo.columns.2.x)")
            print("\(newHomo.columns.0.y)\t\(newHomo.columns.1.y)\t\(newHomo.columns.2.y)")
            print("\(newHomo.columns.0.z)\t\(newHomo.columns.1.z)\t\(newHomo.columns.2.z)")
            
        }

        if let resultT = requestTranslation.results?.first as? VNImageTranslationAlignmentObservation
        {
            
            print("resultT =  \(resultT)")
            x = resultT.alignmentTransform;

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        print("bad")
        return nil
    }

    return x
```

In the x value I get only the Translational matrix (tx and ty), so how I can find rotation and scale matrix?

The homography don't help me its too different from OpenCV homography, even after the transformation.

I'm using Xcode 12 and iOS 14